# Sum column in addtion to display its unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wondering if you can help me with this one.
We have a table called `Part_Locations`. This table contains a list of `Part_ID`, `Location ID`, and `QTY`.

I created a `Parts By Location` report that works great but now the user wants to know what is the total on hand for that part is.

I tried:

```
SELECT part_id,qty, SUM(qty) 
FROM part_location 
GROUP BY part_id
```

But that returns:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'part_location.QTY' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

When I try:

```
SELECT part_id, SUM(qty) 
FROM part_location 
GROUP BY part_id
```

I get `QTY` to sum but then I lose visibility on how many part is at each location.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Could you share your query?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this window function to select part of your query

```
SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY part_id) SumQty
```

like this;

```
SELECT 
  part_id, 
  qty, 
  SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY part_id) SumQty  
FROM part_location
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want an aggregation query.  You want to use a window function:

```
SELECT part_id, qty, SUM(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY part_id)
FROM part_location ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main conceptual issue with this query is that you're mixing `qty` and `SUM(qty)` in the returned result set. Remove `qty` and you should be fine

Comment: Yea, that was my problem is the user wants to see both.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
SELECT 
pl.part_id,
pl.qty,
(SELECT SUM(p.qty) FROM part_location p WHERE p.part_id = pl.part_id)
FROM part_location pl
```